# Can Xbee communicate with Probee?

Tags: compatibility, xbee, zigbee

I have two Zigbee modules:

- Probee ZU10
  https://www.tigal.com/product/2093
- Xbee Series 2
  http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/XB24-Z7WIT-004/602-1098-ND/1942304

I want to communicate with these two Zigbee modules. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible if they are both configured for the same ZigBee network.  Note that you'll need to set `ATZS` to 2 on the XBee modules since you're going to use the ZigBee standard instead of a running a proprietary XBee network.  You won't be able to send Remote AT commands, or use the XBee module's "Transparent Serial" cluster.  You'll need to have a host library for the XBee that supports ZDO and ZCL protocol layers of the ZigBee standard.

If you're using C, you can make use of this [Open Source library](https://github.com/tomlogic/xbee_ansic_library) on GitHub that includes ZDO and ZCL.